# SQL Max over multiple versions

Tags: sql, max, greatest-n-per-group, teradata

I have a table with three columns

```
Product        Version        Price
1              1              25
1              2              15
1              3              25
2              1              8
2              2              8
2              3              4
3              1              25
3              2              10
3              3              5
```

I want to get the max price and the max version by product.
So in the above example the results would have product 1, version 3, price25. product 2, version 2, price 8.

Can you let me know how I would do this.

I'm on Teradata

Comment: What about product 3? Should it be `3, 1, 25`?

Comment: product 3 would be version 1 price 25 @AndriyM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Teradata supports the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SELECT
  Product,
  Version,
  Price
FROM (
  SELECT
    atable.*,  /* or specify column names explicitly as necessary */
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product
                       ORDER BY Price DESC, Version DESC) AS rn
  FROM atable
) s
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Comment: I'm sure this must be it, but I'm finding it hard to adapt it

Comment: Well, I thought I used exact same column names as in your example. What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: for 'atable' i have a select/from query wrapped in () b. When I try to run it, I get a message 'select * must have a from clause, I looked over it and it looks like it does

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to format this to look like code-   SELECT  
  product,  
  version,  
  price  
FROM (  
  SELECT  
    *,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product  
                       ORDER BY price DESC, version DESC) AS rn  
  FROM (select product, version, sum(items) as price from tableran a     
                    group by product, version) b  
) s  
WHERE rn = 1

Comment: Try replacing the `*` near the ROW_NUMBER either with an explicit column list or with `b.*`. I think Oracle is one other SQL product that would complain in this case too.

Comment: You! dear sir, are a genius

Comment: You are very kind, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Using Teradata SQL this can be further simplified:

```
SELECT * FROM atable
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (PARTITION BY Product
         ORDER BY Price DESC, Version DESC) = 1;
```

The QUALIFY is a Teradata extension to Standard SQL, it's similar to a HAVING for GROUP BY, it filters the result of a window function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product
     , max(version) as version 
     , max(price) as price
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY product
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will return version 3 and price 8 for the example table above. I need it to return version 2 price 8 @Kobi

Answer (score 0):

Following code will select product, Highest value of version, Highest value of price and will sort at product using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT [product], MAX([version]) as [MaxVersion], MAX([price]) as [MaxPrice]
FROM [NameOfTable]
GROUP BY [product]
```

More explanation on `Max` function:
[Max function SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately this will return version 3 and price 8 for the example table above. I need it to return version 2 price 8 @MaxMommersteeg

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select p.Product, MAX(p.Price), (select MAX(Version) from Products where Product = p.Product and Price = MAX(p.price))
from Products as p
group by p.Product
```

it returns 
(Product,  price,version)
1     25    3  , 
2     8 2  ,
3     25    1